# JQuery - change JSON label name after the fact

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following JSON data which is from a Facebeook Graph API call:

```
var data = [{"name":"Jonathan Montiel","id":"6546478"},{"name":"Jackson C. Gomes","id":"65654"}];
```

However, I'm using JQuery autocomplete which requires fields to be named (I believe) `label` and `value`

**QUESTION** Is there an easy way to change "name" to "label" and "id" to "value" without doing a huge PHP str_replace or something like that?

Comment: Assuming you really have JSON (the code you posted is a JavaScript array of objects), parse it, create a new array with the appropriate structure while copying the existing values, and convert the new array back to JSON (all in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you might want to change them manually after deconding to an associative array

```
$array = array('name'=>'Jonathan Montiel','id'=>'6546478');

$newkeys = array('name' => 'label', 'id' => 'value');

$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[ $newkeys[ $key ] ] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it's pretty easy: assuming you have a javascript object (which is what it looks like), just change the fields:

```
var data = data[0], // your data is first element in an array
    new_data = {},
    k;

for (k in data) {
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(data, k)) {
    if (k === 'name') k = 'label';
    else if (k === 'id') k = 'value';

    new_data[k] = data[k];
  }
}

// new_data is the correct format now
console.log(new_data);
```

If you have a a JSON string, you could just do a regex replace:

```
var new_json = data[0].replace(/\"([\w_\$]+)\":/g, function (all, key) {
  if (key === 'name') key = 'label';
  else if (key === 'id') key = 'value';
  return '"' + key + '":';
});
```

The PHP equivalent would be pretty similar:

```
$new_json = preg_replace_callback('/\"([\w_\$]+)\":/', function ($matches) {
  if ($matches[1] == 'name') {
    return '"label":';
  } else if ($matches[1] == 'id') {
    return '"value":';
  }
  return $matches[0];
}, $data[0]);
```